# Need help to get system information using php

Tags: size, monitor

is this possible to get screen/monitor size of user,who visited my website???
I am using php as frontend...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it by using javascript:

```
window.screen.availHeight
window.screen.availWidth
```